# Extracting Output in Shell

Tags: shell, osx

When I am doing

```
ls -la |grep -e Aug
```

I am getting the output as

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root           staff   454 Oct 15 18:35 Aug.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 PrashastKumar  staff     0 Aug 25 04:00 abc7.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 PrashastKumar  staff     0 Aug 26 07:00 def7.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 PrashastKumar  staff     0 Aug 27 10:00 ghi7.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 PrashastKumar  staff     0 Aug 28 13:00 jkl7.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 PrashastKumar  staff     0 Aug 29 16:00 mno7.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 PrashastKumar  staff     0 Aug 30 19:00 pqr7.txt
```

I only want to list the files which are created on Aug not the first file which is created on Oct but has name Aug in it. Below should be the output

```
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 PrashastKumar  staff     0 Aug 25 04:00 abc7.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 PrashastKumar  staff     0 Aug 26 07:00 def7.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 PrashastKumar  staff     0 Aug 27 10:00 ghi7.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 PrashastKumar  staff     0 Aug 28 13:00 jkl7.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 PrashastKumar  staff     0 Aug 29 16:00 mno7.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 PrashastKumar  staff     0 Aug 30 19:00 pqr7.txt
```

Also i want to take the month as user input not the hardcoded value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider alternatives to [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), which is [rife with multiple pitfalls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls). But since your main interest here seems to be how to filter by column, and your ultimate goal may not be to parse `ls`  anyway, I'll go ahead and stick with the example you're using (which uses `ls`). Please don't take this to mean parsing `ls`'s output is a good thing to do, though. It's not usually a good thing to do.

When you `grep` for `Aug`, you're searching for it anywhere in a line. Really you don't want to select lines that contain `Aug` anywhere, but instead just those that have it as the complete and exact text of their sixth column. Although you *can* do this with `grep`, it is much easier and more natural with `awk`:

```bash
ls -la | awk '$6 == "Aug"'
```

If for some reason you *really* want to do this with `grep`, you can:

```bash
ls -la | grep -E '(\S+\s+){5}Aug\s'
```

---

You are [also interested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398308/extracting-output-in-shell#comment711180_398312) in filtering for lines whose sixth column is equal to a value that has been read into a shell variable `month`. You have observed that this does *not* work:

```bash
ls -la | awk '$6 == "$month"'   # does not work
```

The reason that does not work is that the [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) around the AWK script `$6 == "$month"` prevent the shell from performing [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) on `$month` to replace it with its value. The text `$month` is passed as-is to `awk`, which is not what you want. [AWK variables and shell variables are completely separate.](https://askubuntu.com/a/964766/22949) One clean and easy way to solve this problem is to initialize an AWK variable from the shell variable using the `awk` command's `-v` option:

```bash
ls -la | awk -v m="$month" '$6 == m'
```

You could name your AWK variable the same as your shell variable, if you like. This is a reasonable choice in cases like this where they represent the same thing. I've named the AWK variable `m`, to illustrate how shell and AWK variables are separate and also to avoid confusion. (For long or complicated AWK scripts, or those with many variables, you would probably want to name the variable more descriptively than just `m`, but in this case no readability is sacrificed.)

---

<sup>I've linked above to topics in the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) because you've tagged your question [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) and the default shell in all but the very oldest versions of OS X (now called macOS) is `bash`. In very old versions it was `tcsh`.</sup>

<sup>As a side note, you mentioned that you took the value of `month` as input with the command `read month`. When you use your shell's `read` command, you should almost always pass the `-r` flag, and thus write `read -r month` instead. Only omit `-r` if you *want* the `read` command to translate `\` escapes in the input it receives (which you virtually never want). You may also want to use `IFS= read -r month`, so leading and trailing whitespace are not stripped. In this case, though, you likely do want it removed and can thus omit `IFS=`.</sup>

Comment: But when i am reading month from user as read month & passing the command as ls -la |awk ' $6 == "$month" ', its not working  what is the reason for that

Comment: @Prashast That's because `month` is a shell variable but the single quotes prevent the shell from expanding it before running `awk`. It seems to me that using a month name stored in a shell variable is an important part of what you're trying to do, so I've expanded my answer with an additional section about how to solve this problem. I would encourage you to edit your question and add that as well, though, so other readers know it's part of what you want to know. Other users may post helpful answers (like about doing it without `ls`) that will be more helpful if they know you want this.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
ls -al | awk '$6 == "Aug" {print}'
```

Comment: No need to repeat it; just vote up and accept Eliah's answer.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks; this answer was actually [posted about eight seconds before mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/398308/timeline), though.